# DatabaseException: Failed to get FirebaseDatabase instance: Specify DatabaseURL within FirebaseApp or from your GetInstance() call

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I'm just testing if I could try to send data in my firebase database but I'm stuck at fixing this kind of error. "Failed to get to get FirebaseDatabase instance". I have no idea what's happening.

```
void TryDataSend(){   
   DatabaseReference root = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to connect to the Firebase database, the `FirebaseDatabase` object needs to know the URL of that database. It typically will:

- either read this from the `google-services.json` (Android)or `GoogleService-Info.plist` (iOS) file upon startup as documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup#add-config-file),
- or you can specify the URL in code, passing it to[`FirebaseDatabase.GetInstance`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/database/firebase-database#class_firebase_1_1_database_1_1_firebase_database_1a09a327124d0bdf5bab77e49bf531eedd).

The error message seems to indicate that neither of these things happened, so I recommend checking the links and see if you've taken all the steps.

Comment: I think I have downloaded google-service.json for ios. I'll check first. Thank you so much.

Comment: Sorry, I'm kinda new to Stackoverflow. I've already checkmark it but I need at least 15 reputations to vote. It may take a while. Thanks again.